# Linear system solver c++

Tags: c++, matrix, solver

I have been working on this matrix class. I have already done a function to calculate the determinant by Gauss elimination, and I store the triangular matrix in a private member of my class.

I then added a resolve function that takes a vector b as parameter and solves the following:

```
Mat<M,N> * X<M,1> = b<M,1>
```

I used backward substitution and I can't figure out why I'm not getting the right results. Here is my code:

## Determinant function that works:

```
float determinant()
{
    if(M != N)
    {
        std::cerr <<" Matrix is not square!!!" << std::endl;
        return std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
    }
    else
    {


    float c;
    std::vector<float> temp;

    temp = this->mat;

    for(int j=0; j<M; j++)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                if(i>j)
                {
                    c=this->at(i,j)/this->at(j,j);
                    for(int k=0; k<M+1; k++)
                    {
                        at(i,k) = at(i,k) - c* at(j,k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    c=1;
    for(int i=0; i<M;i++)
        c *= at(i,i);

    m_tri = this->mat;
    this->mat = temp;

    return c;
    }
}
```

## Solve function that doesn't work:

```
Mat<M,1> resolve (Mat<M,1> b)
{

    this->determinant();
    Mat<M,1> sol;
    sol.resize(M);

    sol(M-1,0) = b(M-1,0)/m_tri[(M-1)*M+(M-1)];

     for (int i=(M-2); i>=0; i--)
        {
          sol(i,0)= b(i,0);
            for (int j=i+1; j<M; j++)
            {
                 sol(i,0) -= m_tri[(j)*M + i]*sol(j,0);
            }
          sol(i,0) = sol(i,0) / m_tri[(i)*M + i];
        }
     return sol;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick glance -- your determinant() function appears to be destructive to your matrix.

Comment: i store the data before starting the calculation then i get back once i store the triangular matrix , the data of my matrix is stored in a vector !

Comment: @Atomic_alarm sorry what is MCVE ?

Comment: @BobMaza http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve